# Mean square ergodic process: Uniform tail convergence of the time average?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

Consider a diffusion process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ satisfying mean-square ergodicity
\begin{align*}
\bar X_t := \frac{1}{t}\int_0^tX_t\,dt \;{\stackrel{L^2}{\longrightarrow}}\;\bar X,\quad t\to\infty,
\end{align*}
As an example, we can think about an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process
\begin{align*}
dX_t = a(b-X_t)\,dt + \sigma\, dW_t,
\end{align*}
for which it is easy to show that $\mathbb{E}[(\bar X_t-b)^2]\to 0$, as $t\to\infty$.

Do this imply some kind of a uniform tail convergence for the time average? For example, 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\geq t_0}(\bar X_t-\bar X)^2]\longrightarrow 0,\quad t_0\to\infty, 
\end{align*}
or that for every $\epsilon>0$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[\sup_{t\geq t_0}(\bar X_t-\bar X)^2\geq \epsilon]\longrightarrow 0,\quad t_0\to\infty, 
\end{align*}
or something weaker than that?